# Getting selected image of photo chooser task to image control C# Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Trying to get the selected image from the photo chooser task into a image control.
But I got an error of

```
"Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush' 
to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'"
```

How should i go about doing it?

The code i used:

```
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            ImageBrush bgImage = new ImageBrush();
            bgImage.ImageSource = App.globalData.bitmapImage;
            image1.Source = bgImage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicall, the error is saying that you're trying to set your ImageSource of bgImage to an existing imagebrush.

Try changing your code to the following:

```
base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
image1.Source = App.globalData.bitmapImage;
```

You're getting that error because you're trying to create a new brush and assign an existing imagebrush as it's imagesource property. Since you already have an imagebrush (App.globalData.bitmapImage) then you can just remove all the logic that has to do with creating the brush and assign it directly to the source of your image. (image1.Source = App.globalData.bitmapImage;)

P.S.

Here is some code that I use to get a photo from the photochooser task:

```
    private void PhotoChooserCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            var img = new BitmapImage();
            img.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks now i know what is the reason behind it. By the way is there a way to check if a image control is empty?

Comment: What do you mean by empty? If you mean that the source is not set then yes, you can check for a null value. (Which is the default for the Source property) - if(image1.Source == null)

Comment: I wanted to check if the image control is currently displaying a image in it.

Comment: Then yes, you can just check the Source property. If the property is null then the Image is not displaying anything. As far as display though, you might want to consider using Visibility to show and hide an image from being displayed rather than nulling out it's source property.